# Adding a custom value to survey monkey API response

Tags: surveymonkey

I am building an application that pulls data for certain surveys from survey monkey. In my application, each survey is connected to an organisation. One organisation can have multiple surveys and each survey has only one organisation.

When I pull the data for a survey (GET request on /surveys/{id}/details) I would like to be able to add the organisation id to the survey monkey response, so that I would know to which organisation is that survey connected. Is there a way to add a custom variable of this type on survey monkey ?

If adding a variable of this type is not possible, what is the best way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a good way to tag surveys in the API right now. [Survey folders](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/How-do-I-add-folders-or-move-surveys-into-folders) may be supported in the future which will allow you to move a Survey into a folder for each organisation.

In the meantime, you can add [custom variables](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) (URL GET parameters) to a response (assuming you're using a [weblink collector](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-collectors)) which would let you know which organisation that response belongs to. You need to add the custom variables on the Survey, then when sending out the weblink add the parameter, something like:

```
https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/2Q3RXZB?organization_id=<org_id>
```

Or if you're using an email collector you can put [extra fields](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-recipients) on the recipient (or custom fields on the contact, if the contact is always in that one organisation) that let you know which organisation they belong to.

Another option (which may not be very great) is setting a `nickname` on the Survey which could be checked against when fetching the associated survey, see the [Survey API docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys).